# Proof of an algebraic expression

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I've an expression $\displaystyle \Bbb Z[i]/\langle1+3i\rangle \cong \frac{\Bbb Z[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle}{\langle1+3x,x^2+1\rangle/\langle x^2+1\rangle}$.

I am unable to understand how it comes. I know that $\displaystyle \Bbb Z[i]\cong \Bbb Z[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$. But what about the denominator ?

Comment: It looks like it's just one of the isomorphism theorems.

Comment: # 5 under the third isomorphism theorem for rings. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Third_isomorphism_theorem_2

Comment: No..It is not from 3rd Isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Why does it not follow from the third isomorphism theorem?

Comment: have you tried constructing a function from the left ring to the numerator of the right ring with kernel denominator of the right ring?

Comment: @mdave16 Yes..I have tried..but unable to define such a function. Can you help me to define such a function?

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon Can you tell me how you use third isomophism theorem here ?

Comment: @Topo in answer to how to define such a function... the same way that you define the isomorphism $\mathbb Z[i] \cong \mathbb Z[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$. Perhaps some more information about what you've tried would be useful.

Comment: @Topo, Yeah, like Dustan said, it's more fun to try to construct the function than to give you the function. Although my method is more dry and elementary than the slicker way of applying the third isom theorem. (Essentially, I'm not going to do any work until I see you doing some)